# Custom view with viewpager inside a dialog not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I am trying to inflate a custom dialog with a custom view including a `ViewPager`. I am getting an error like "No view found for the fragment inside the `ViewPager`".
The `ViewPager` seems to be causing some problems here and I couldn't find any answers to this exact case.

tried using `alertdialog.builder` to build the dialog still the error is persisting. Tried to get the correct context still could not solve the error.

A link to the repo can be found here - https://github.com/Alfurquan/CustomCalendarView

This is my main activity's onCreate

```java
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_month_picker);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.clickToOpn);
        customMonthPicker = findViewById(R.id.customMonthPicker1);
//        customMonthPicker.setOnMonthSelectedListener(new OnMonthSelectedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onSelectedMonth(int month) {
//                Log.d("msgMonth", String.valueOf(month));
//            }
//        });
//
//        customMonthPicker.setOnYearSelectedListener(new OnYearSelectedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onYearSelected(int year) {
//                Log.d("msgYear", String.valueOf(year));
//            }
//        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CustomMonthAndYearPickerDialog dialog = new CustomMonthAndYearPickerDialog(MonthPickerActivity.this);
                dialog.setOnMonthSelectedListener(new OnMonthSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelectedMonth(int month) {
                        Log.d("msgMonth", String.valueOf(month));
                    }
                });

                dialog.setOnYearSelectedListener(new OnYearSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onYearSelected(int year) {
                        Log.d("msgYear", String.valueOf(year));

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

This is the custom dialog code

```
public CustomMonthAndYearPickerDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_month_dialog);
        mContext = context;
        initialize();
        setClickListeners();
    }



    public CustomMonthAndYearPickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
    }

    protected CustomMonthAndYearPickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, @Nullable OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }
    private void initialize() {
        customMonthPicker = findViewById(R.id.customMonthPicker1);
        btnDone = findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
        btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1);
    }
```

This is the custom view code

```java
 Activity activity = getActivityFromContext(getContext());
        yearPagerAdapter = new YearPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager(),context,fragList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(yearPagerAdapter);


 @Nullable
    public Activity getActivityFromContext(@NonNull Context context){
        while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
            if (context instanceof Activity) return (Activity) context;
            context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
        }
        return null; //we failed miserably
    }
```

this is the viewpager adapter

```
public class YearPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    YearFragment[] fragList;
    private CalendarManager calendarManager;

    public YearPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context,YearFragment[] fragList) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.fragList = fragList;
        calendarManager = new CalendarManager(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public void setYears(Calendar currentYear){

        Calendar prevYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        prevYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
        prevYear.add(Calendar.MONTH,-12);
        int prev = prevYear.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
        nextYear.add(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
        int next = nextYear.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cur = currentYear.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        ArrayList<Integer> prevYears,currentYears,nextYears;
        prevYears = calendarManager.getYearList(prevYear);
        nextYears = calendarManager.getYearList(nextYear);
        currentYears = calendarManager.getYearList(currentYear);

        fragList[0].updateUI(prevYears);
        fragList[1].updateUI(currentYears);
        fragList[2].updateUI(nextYears);

    }
}
```

this is the fragment

```
package com.example.customcalendar.fragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.example.customcalendar.R;
import com.example.customcalendar.adapter.YearGridAdapter;
import com.example.customcalendar.interfaces.OnYearSelectedListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class YearFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Integer> yearList;
    private View view;
    private GridView yearGrid;
    int currentYear;
    public static int selectedYear;
    private YearGridAdapter yearGridAdapter;
    public static OnYearSelectedListener onYearSelectedListener;
    public YearFragment() {

    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public YearFragment(ArrayList<Integer> yearList) {
        this.yearList = yearList;
    }

    public static YearFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> yearList){
        return new YearFragment(yearList);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.year_view,container,false);
        initializeVariables();
        setUpYearGridAdapter();
        setUpYearGridClicks();
        return view;
    }

    private void initializeVariables() {
        yearGrid = view.findViewById(R.id.yearGrid);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        selectedYear = currentYear;
    }

    private void setUpYearGridAdapter() {
        yearGridAdapter = new YearGridAdapter(view.getContext(),yearList,currentYear,selectedYear);
        yearGrid.setAdapter(yearGridAdapter);
    }

    private void setUpYearGridClicks() {
        yearGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                int year = yearGridAdapter.getItem(position);
                selectedYear = year;
                onYearSelectedListener.onYearSelected(selectedYear);
                setUpYearGridAdapter();
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateUI(ArrayList<Integer> yearList){
        this.yearList = yearList;
        setUpYearGridAdapter();
    }


}
```

this is the xml of dialog

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/monthName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="April"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/yearName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2019"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2sp"
    android:background="@color/grey"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.customcalendar.views.CustomMonthPicker
        android:id="@+id/currentMonthPicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel1"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDone1"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Done"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
Error message - "Process: com.example.customcalendar, PID: 17596
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0700ab (com.example.customcalendar:id/yearPager) for fragment YearFragment{20a1ebd5 #0 id=0x7f0700ab android:switcher:2131165355:1}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: @Mr.Patel: The viewpager is bringing over some problems in this scenario. This question is not a duplicate of the one you mentioned.

Comment: Could you provide your xml?

Comment: @Sp4Rx i have posted the xml for custom dialog the others are in the repo Link:-https://github.com/Alfurquan/CustomCalendarView

Comment: First of all you have given your whole project to debug, please have a read of the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

What I've seen in your code is your `ViewPager` inside your `CustomMonthPicker` is causing this crash, I would suggest you should go with `RecyclerView` as it will reduce complexity.

**NB:** Also avoid casting `Context` to `AppCompatActivity`.